# Rspec test not hitting controller update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write a simple test to validate updating an `Employee` and while it works in practice I wanted to write the test anyway.

```
RSpec.describe EmployeesController, type: :controller do

    before(:each) do
      admin_user = FactoryBot.create(
        :user,
        user_type: 1,
        email: "admin@admin.com",
        password: "oeifhoi2345tf",
        password_confirmation: "oeifhoi2345tf"
      )
      login_as(admin_user)

      @employee = create(:employee)
    end

    it 'expects employee values to update following update' do
        p @employee
        put :update, params: { 
            id: @employee[:id], 
            employee: { name: "New Name" }
        }
        @employee.reload
        p @employee

        expect(@employee.name).to eq("New Name")
    end
end
```

The test fails and `@employee.name` remains unchanged.  I have a feeling the update it not even occurring because I added a print line to my controller and I do not see it in my logs:

```
def update
    p "IN UPDATE"

    if @employee.update(employee_params)
        redirect_to edit_employee_path(@employee[:id])
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Is there something I am missing in my `put` call?

Comment: What happens when you change `@employee.reload` to `@employee.reload!`? How about when you change `update` to `update!`?Ultimately I think the problem here is that the update actually takes place in the model but you are testing with a controller/request test.  You should only be testing what happens in the controller(redirects, status codes, response bodies ect).  It would be like telling a waiter "I want a hamburger but tell the chef to make sure the grill is set to med-high and that he grills it for 2:00 on each side"

Comment: Could it be that employees/update is not a PUT route? Otherwise the test seems fine at a glance.

Comment: Check `log/test.log` to see the actual request.

Comment: It's so strange.  I've tried `put` and `patch`.  My route is working fine.  There is no call to the controller update at all.

Comment: inspec the body of the response after calling update, check the log too, maybe you are not signed in properly or some before_action is preventing the action to really be executed

Comment: @arieljuod your last comment made my day <3

Comment: most likely an authentication issue